How to send several tasks in one single request in Google Cloud Tasks?
I am in the process of migrating a queuing system deployed on AWS that uses SQS to Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Taks.
The current solution uses the method ⁠sendMessageBatch to send up to 10 messages per request. Reading the Cloud Tasks API documentation I didn't find a similar solution.
Is it possible to submit more than one task in a single request via Cloud Tasks, if so, how?
I read the documentation and forums but didn't find anything related

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
